# Как прописать в SQL дату начала и конец действия цены?

Tags: postgresql

Мне необходимо из данной таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сформировать таблицу такого типа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN valid_from_dt date;` и `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN valid_to_dt date;`

Comment: Вам нужно хранить исторические данные? Это реализуется во многих СУБД с помощью так называемых Temporal tables. Ищите по этому термину и найдёте немало примеров. [1](https://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/), [2](https://github.com/nearform/temporal_tables), [3](https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/temporal-tables-for-postgresql-15/)

Comment: Мне нужно на основе даты создания так называемого товара сделать строки с датами с которой началась действовать данная цена и с датой конца действия цены.

Answer (score 0):

Добавление столбцов таблицы делается через [ALTER TABLE](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-altertable)
В вашем случае имеет смысл рассмотреть вариант с использованием диапазонного
типа [daterange](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/rangetypes)

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS entity
    ADD COLUMN date_range_price daterange;
```

Использование диапазонного типа упростить проверку вхождения даты покупки в диапазон действия цены, облегчит контроль не пересечения диапазонов действия цен на один и тот же товар, что необходимо для исключения неоднозначности. [Диапазонные функции и операторы](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/functions-range#range-operators-table)